# AttributeError: module 'urllib3' has no attribute 'HTTPHeaderDict'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, python-3.9

I am trying to send headers from lambda into an API.I have taken `HTTPHeaderDict` from https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html .

```
import urllib3
import os
import json

# Get environment variable
api_url = os.getenv('API_URL')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    request = json.loads(json.dumps(event))
    print(json.dumps(request['headers']))
    headers = request['headers']
    
    request_headers = urllib3.HTTPHeaderDict()
    for key in headers:
        request_headers.add(key, headers[key])
    
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    response = http.request('GET', api_url + '/', headers=request_headers, timeout=10)

    
    return {
        'statusCode': response.status,
        'headers': response.headers,
        'body': response.data
    }
```

I see the error in cloudwatch

[ERROR] AttributeError: module 'urllib3' has no attribute 'HTTPHeaderDict'

Comment: Any reason to not just use the `request['headers']` dict directly? It's not required to pass a HTTPHeaderDict, a regualr dict just works fine. The only reason I can think of would be if you need duplicate keys in the dict, but since the source is already a dict, that can't happen.

Comment: @mata I get `[ERROR] Runtime.MarshalError: Unable to marshal response: Object of type HTTPHeaderDict is not JSON serializable` on lambda

Comment: @mata If i use the request['headers'] directly coming from API gateway i get `Runtime.MarshalError: Unable to marshal response: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 2: invalid start byte Traceback (most recent call last):`

Answer (score 3):

What version of `urllib3` are you using? If you are using the latest `pip` installed package which is version `1.26.7` it won't have it exposed at the package import level. If you look at the docs for the latest [stable release](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide.html) you'll see that it isn't mentioned as an import level Class.

The link you linked too is for `2.0.0dev0` version which you'll have to install from the github repo itself. If you can't install from the repo you should be able to access the `HTTPHeaderDict` class from the `_collections` module like `from urllib3._collections import HTTPHeaderDict` and then call it as `request_headers = HTTPHeaderDict()`.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTPHeaderDict seems to be not serializable and the error was in the way i was sending the response.

```
import urllib3
import os
import json
#from urllib3._collections import HTTPHeaderDict

# Get environment variable
api_url = os.getenv('API_URL')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    request = json.loads(json.dumps(event))
    
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    response = http.request('GET', api_url + '/', headers=request['headers'], timeout=10)
    response_headers = {}
    for header_key in response.headers:
        response_headers[header_key] = response.headers[header_key] 
    
    return {
        'statusCode': response.status,
        'headers' : response_headers,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

I had to loop through the `HTTPHeaderDict` and put the value in another dictionary.As pointed by @mata `request['headers']` can be used directly.

P.S I couldn't find aws docs that indicate which version of `urllib3` is used for AWS Lambda functions

Comment: You can deploy an AWS  lambda function with any version of dependencies you need https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html